# Variable holds previous value even when new value assigned

Tags: powershell, operator-precedence

I am probably missing something simple but...

My code:

```
$BusinessUnits = @()
$Animal = 'DOG'

if (-not $BusinessUnits -contains $Animal) {
    $Animal + " NOT FOUND. ADDING"
    $BusinessUnits += $Animal
} else {
    $Animal + " FOUND"
}

$Animal = 'Mouse'
if (-not $BusinessUnits -Contains $Animal) {
    $Animal + " NOT FOUND. ADDING"
    $BusinessUnits += $Animal
} else {
    $Animal + " FOUND"
}
$BusinessUnits
```

Above code returns:

```
DOG NOT FOUND. ADDING
Mouse FOUND
DOG
```

The first if does not find DOG so adds it; however, the second if finds Mouse and does not add it. Mouse is NOT in the array at this point.

What have I done wrong?

I'm writing code to create a CSV file as part of some processing. The values for business unit will not be constant and may vary during processing. And I only want to write the header row when the first detail row is added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-not` operator has higher [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence?view=powershell-3.0) than the `-contains` operator, so you're effectively checking

```
(-not $BusinessUnits) -contains $Animal
```

rather than what you actually want to check

```
-not ($BusinessUnits -contains $Animal)
```

Use either parentheses (see above) or the `-notcontains` operator to avoid this gotcha.

```
$BusinessUnits -notcontains $Animal
```